# ESLint Airbnb ES6 and Redux Async Action Unexpected block statement surrounding arrow body

Tags: redux, eslint, arrow-functions, thunk

[image]

What am I doing wrong? I have like three other async actions that have the same issue and can't fix it.

Comment: Just FYI its easier if you add your code in with your question rather than a screenshot

Comment: The rule is to prevent unnecessary nesting. The idea being that `x => y => x + y` is clearer than the nested alternative.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

When you take a look at the [Arrow Function Documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)

```
(param1, param2, …, paramN) => expression
// equivalent to:  => { return expression; }
```

the "Unexpected block statement surrounding arrow body" just means that you don't need a `{ return expression; }` block for your arrow function here, as the arrow function does return by default.

```
const getOptions = () => (dispatch, getState) => {}
```

is equivalent to

```
const getOptions = () => { return (dispatch, getState) => {} }
```

and therefore the block statement is unnecessary

Answer (score 2):

**Not recommended:**
You can always disable the [arrow-body-style](http://eslint.org/docs/rules/arrow-body-style) rule or configure it in a way that it doesn't give such errors.

**Recommended:**

```
const getOptions = () => ( dispatch, getState ) => {
    const {user} = getState();
    //rest of the code
}
```

This basically means that we don't have to write `{ return` thing when we are only returning w/o doing anything else